Integration Testing for non-http based Standard Logic App workflows
We have a requirement to perform integration test for Standard Logic Apps Non-http based triggers.
We must automate it in GitHub pipelines.
Lot of online examples are showcasing only for http based triggers.
We have workflows with triggers such as "Service Bus based", "Recurrence" based.
Is is possible to test these workflows ? Need some references.
Preferred written in DotNet or Powershell/other scripting
Not able to find much examples for my requirement.

What type of connections are you making to the services?  Are you using pipes/streams?  PS is written in Net library so you may be able to find a c# example that you can convert to PS.

@jdweng Service bus trigger is when a message in available in queue. Then the workflow automatically trigger and we process the values in the message content and push to some other queue or store in a blob based on the requirement

You can always send a broadcast UDP message and for testing register to receive the UDP.

Can you please share some example?
